# "".All(char.IsNumber) Returns True

Tags: c#, linq

Why does `"".All(char.IsNumber)` return `true`?
According to the method summary, the `All()` method:

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

This doesn't seem very accurate since none of the elements of the sequence satisfy the condition due to the fact that there are no elements to begin with.

Comment: Just [in](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) case, [here is an MCVE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gG2yGe).

Comment: [MSDN, in the Returns section.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2) "true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty;" Your enumerable is empty so it returns `true`.

Comment: My fault for only reading the summary. Thanks @Loocid

Comment: This definition of the semantics of `All` on empty sequences ultimately derives from mathematical logic, where the for-all quantifier works this way on empty sets. This is explained in the answers to this question on the Mathematics SE: [Why is predicate “all” as in all(SET) true if the SET is empty?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is documented that way - [MSDN, in the Returns section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2#returns) (as Loocid noted in a comment):

> `true` if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, `false`.

And the reason it is defined to do this is because this definition of the semantics of All on empty sequences ultimately derives from mathematical logic, where the for-all quantifier works this way on empty sets. This is explained in the answers to this question on the Mathematics SE: [Why is predicate “all” as in all(SET) true if the SET is empty?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty)

Comment: You should add the relevant quotes from both links in your answer.

Comment: Fine for the quote from MSDN, but is it really necessary to quote from various answers on another SE question (even though it is a different SE site)? By site policy it isn't going anywhere.  (Seriously, asking because I don't know.)

Comment: you have a point there - it's unlikely stackoverflow will outlive Math.stackexchange - but it's not only for the sake of links going stale, it's also to make the answer more readable. As a rule of thumb, a stackoverflow post (answer or question, doesn't matter) should be self contained. Links should be used as "bonus reading" or to support your claims. Come to think of it, this is exactly what the link to math.se is in your answer. +1.